# SQLite - condition check before execute a section of script

Tags: sqlite

I understand that SQLite does not have If-Else condition check, and people have been using case statements to get around it.  However I want to do a if condition check before executing a certain portion of the script, like the following:

```
IF (condition = true)

INSERT INTO tableA(A, B)
VALUES (a, b)

....

END
```

From what I have been trying, case statement doesn't seem to work.  Is there any way I can accomplish the above in SQLite?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "script"?

Comment: well accordant to this https://www.sqliteconcepts.org/pl_if.html sqlite support if then statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use an `INSERT SELECT`

INSERT INTO table SELECT ...;

> The second form of the INSERT statement contains a SELECT statement
>   instead of a VALUES clause.
>
> - A new entry is inserted into the table for
>     each row of data returned by executing the SELECT statement.
> - If a
>     column-list is specified, the number of columns in the result of the
>     SELECT must be the same as the number of items in the column-list.
> - Otherwise, if no column-list is specified, the number of columns in
>     the result of the SELECT must be the same as the number of columns in
>     the table.
> - Any SELECT statement, including compound SELECTs and SELECT
>     statements with ORDER BY and/or LIMIT clauses, may be used in an
>     INSERT statement of this form.
>
>   - [extract from SQL As Understood By SQLite - INSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

e.g.

```
INSERT into xxx 
SELECT null as id,
    CASE
        WHEN filesize < 1024 THEN 'just a little bit'
        WHEN filesize >= 1024 THEN 'quite a bit'
    END AS othercolumn
FROM filesizes
WHERE filesize < 1024 * 1024
```

The above will insert rows into table **xxx**  which consists of 2 columns **`id`** (rowid alias) and **`othercolumn`** according to the results (2 columns **id** (always set as null) and  **othercolumn**) of the `SELECT`, which is selecting from the filesizes table where the value of the filesize column is less than 1024 * 1024 (1048576), thus conditionally inserting.

Furthermore, if the filesize is less than 1024 the **othercolumn** is set to **just a little bit**, if the filesize is greater than 1023 then the **othercolumn** is set to **quite a bit**. So making the conditional insert more complex.

Assuming the **filesizes** table were :-

[image]

The running the above would result in :-

[image]